# Repetir consulta com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando atualizar uma div constantemente e no entanto este código abaixo apenas atualiza uma única vez, gostaria de instruções de como fazer atualiza-lo sempre a um determinado tempo para que assim a mesma ação seja repetida inúmeras vezes.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Refresh sem atualizar página</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <body>

        <div id="panel">teste</div>
        <input id="changePanel" value="Change Panel" type="hidden">

        <script>
        $("#changePanel").click(function() {
            var data = "testando";
            $("#panel").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
        });

        window.setTimeout(function(){
           document.getElementById("changePanel").click();
        }, 2000);
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse `data` vem de onde? se fôr novos dados que vais buscar via servidor isso devia ser feito de outra maneira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude o seu código para:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
       document.getElementById("changePanel").click();
 }, 2000);
```

Porém sugiro, que ao invés de simular o click, encapsule uma função com o código que quer executar no click e configure ela no `setInterval`:

```
function atualizarDiv() {
    var data = "testando";
    $("#panel").hide().html(data).fadeIn('fast');
}

$("#changePanel").click(atualizarDiv);

window.setInterval(atualizarDiv, 2000);
```

A função `setInterval` recebe como parâmtros um callback e o tempo em milisegundos do intervalo que deve executar o callback do primeiro parâmetro e retorna um identificador desse `intervalo`. Se precisar interromper a execução desse `intervalo`, utilize a função `clearInterval` passando como argumento o identificador:

```
var idIntervalo = window.clearInterval
// para interromper a execução
window.clearInterval(idIntervalo);
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, muito obrigado.